# How to create categories and subcategories in codeigniter?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, inner-join, parent

I want to make online book sales but I am confused by category and subcategory.

So I decided to create two tables as below :

Table Categories

[image]

Table Product

[image]

Model

```
   <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Product_model extends CI_Model
    {
        var $table = 'product';

        public function ProductsCategories()
        {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('categories');
            $this->db->join('product', 'product.productID = categories.categoriesID','left');

            $query = $this->db->get();

            $products = array();
            if ($query->num_rows()) 
            {
              foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) 
              {
                $products[$row['categoriesName']][] = $row;
              }
            }
            return $query->result_array();
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
session_start();
class Member extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if ($this->session->userdata('username')=="") {
            redirect('auth');
        }
        $this->load->model('product_model','product');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
        $data['member'] = $this->product->all();
        $data['categories'] = $this->product->ProductsCategories();
        $this->load->view('member/index', $data);
    }
}
```

View

```
<div class="yamm-content">
    <div class="row">
    <?php foreach($categories as $categoriesName => $row) : ?>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h5><?php echo $categoriesName;?></h5>
            <ul>
            <?php foreach($row as $product) : ?>
                <li><?php echo anchor('method/'.$row['productID'], $row['productName']); ?></a></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to show you results like this

[image]

Where is the mistake? thanks

Comment: does product_model and product are two different models?

Answer (score 0):

The way you referred to your model is wrong:

```
$data['categories'] = $this->product_model->ProductsCategories();
```

Also, $this->load->model wants an array. so:

```
$this->load->model(array('product_model','product'));
```

Comment: it was only parameter of product_model, sir

Comment: My problem is in a category that does not appear in Yamm-bootstrap